# Resources Exceeded in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, memory, google-bigquery

I am attempting to retrieve a list of organizations from our database based on the organizations' city and state, grouped by an attribute `org_name`. These organizations have multiple nested arrays as other attributes. I have to unnest the `LOCATIONS` aggregated array in order to query the proper locations. Since I am grouping by organization name, I aggregate the remaining desired attributes with `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG` for every array and then run a user defined function called `dedup` to remove any repeated values since all desired attributes must be grouped or aggregated. This works perfectly on a small table, but as I scale up I receive the following error.

`Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 116% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): aggregate functions and GROUP BY clauses: 95% other/unattributed: 5%`.

The code is as follows:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  dedup(val ANY TYPE) AS ((
    SELECT
      ARRAY_AGG(t)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT *
      FROM
        UNNEST(val) v) t ));

SELECT
  org_name,
  dedup(ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(sizes)) AS sizes,
  dedup(ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(org_nums)) AS org_nums,
  dedup(ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(location)) AS location,
  dedup(ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(types_of_professionals)) AS types_of_professionals,
  dedup(ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(specialties)) AS specialties
FROM
  `merging_npi_medicare.practices`,
  UNNEST(location) AS loc
WHERE
  loc.professional_city = "HARRISBURG"
  AND loc.professional_state = "PA"
GROUP BY
  org_name
```

My expected results would be a table of unique organizations with an array of sizes, phone numbers, locations, types of professionals, and specialties. However, I receive the memory exceeded error when I run this code. I understand that the mistake must be with my many aggregated arrays and UDF function calls but I simply do not know how else to achieve what I would like.

The following link demonstrates how I would like the results to look. It was achieved by running the same query as above just with an extra parameter that only looked for organizations with names that included `PINNACLE`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nJpb.png

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to speculate a bit on what the data looks like.  But does rephrasing it like this fix the problem?

```
select org_name,
       (select array_agg(s.size)
        from `merging_npi_medicare.practices` p cross join
             unnest(sizes) s
        where p.org_name = o.org_name
       ) as sizes
from (select distinct org_name
      from `merging_npi_medicare.practices` cross join
           unnest(location) AS loc
      where loc.professional_city = 'HARRISBURG' and
            loc.professional_state = 'PA'
     ) o;
```

Comment: Rephrasing it like that then adding blocks of selects for each desired attribute like that worked perfectly thank you so much!